# Are there rules that say that extremely high ability scores provide additional benefits solely because those ability scores are so high?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

Skills are affected through stats obviously and it's pretty self explanatory how they will affect a skill as it's usually in the description. But what about things outside of skill scaling?

Does a max Charisma give the character a silver tongue? Wisdom, godlike instincts? Dexterity, amazing reflexes? Strength, enough raw power to topple a giant? Intelligence, the understanding of the most complex of subjects? Constitution, insane stamina?

Comment: Have you read the ability scores section of the PHB?  What did you find there?

Comment: @mxyzplk what page? The index always points to incorrect pages on my pdf. AS for as adobe reader is concerned page 173 (bottom right corner) is page 160 and I'd rather not have to constantly improvise in an attempt to find one thing.

Comment: There are no legal PDF versions of the official materials. I would recommend you purchase either the digital access on dndbeyond or the physical books.

Comment: @NautArch My friend gave me it to borrow so I assumed it was legit. Guess I'll have to have a talk with him later on.

Comment: The basic rules available for free on dndbeyond.com include the entire chapter about ability scores, in case that helps.

Comment: The Player's Basic Rules are also available as a free PDF on the official Wizards of the Coast - Dungeons and Dragons website.

Comment: @NautArch In certain countries (including mine) it is legal to make digital copies of copyrighted books acquired legally (including eg. borrowing from a friend or library) as long as they're not redistributed beyond personal use or used commercially. So without commenting on this specific case, one can't make a general statement about pdf materials being illegal.

Comment: Perhaps I am interpreting this question wrong. But a possible rewrite that would draw better answers might be to ask "what ability scores mean quantitatively? Can a hero with 20 STR punch a 200 yo oak down with his bare fists?" Does Bruce Lee have a Dex of 30, or would he translate to a dex of 13? The books, from what I have read, never state what the scale is, just that bigger numbers mean better.

Answer (score 10):

## No, there are no such rules.

Having maximum value ability scores does nothing more than provide modifiers and any other mechanics discussed in the Ability Scores chapter.

You can find that chapter in the PHB under Chapter 7 which covers how Ability Scores are used. These can also be found in the [Basic Rules-Using Ability Scores](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores).

Answer (score 4):

## Nope

They call it **RAW** - Rules as Written.  There are no secret rules.

But feel free to embellish the player's multitude of successes as a DM.

Answer (score 2):

### Strictly No, but there are advantages at modestly high ability scores that could inspire your DM to add more

There is nothing explicitly in the RAW (rules-as-written) to give a "yes" to your question.

However, we could note that the RAW does specify some advantages for higher-than-average ability scores.  Some heavy armor requires Strength 15, and some feats such as Defensive Duelist, Grappler, Inspiring Leader, or Ritual Caster require an ability score of 13.

So if your DM uses feats, then it would be reasonable to ask your DM to add feats with even higher ability score prerequisites, thus creating some form of a "Yes" to your question, when it comes to how your table is run.  Nothing stops your DM from creating feats that require, say, a 15, 17, or even 20 in an ability score, though this is not terribly common.

Furthermore, Xanathar's Guide to Everything puts forth specific benefits for having passive Perception of 20 or 15:

> Whispers don’t disturb sleep, unless a sleeper’s passive Wisdom (Perception) score is 20 or higher and the whispers are within 10 feet of the sleeper. Speech at a normal volume awakens a sleeper if the environment is otherwise silent (no wind, birdsong, crickets, street sounds, or the like) and the sleeper has a passive Wisdom (Perception) score of 15 or higher. ([XGtE](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#WakingSomeone))

Again, this is just support for requesting that your DM consider making a house-rule or a homebrew feat.

Comment: While the lead title does say "extremely high" the body references Max. Not sure if that changes your response, but something to consider that it's not just about having to meet requirements, but if a max score does anything special.

Comment: @NautArch point well taken, edited answer accordingly

Comment: Yeah forgot to fix that I was thinking of making a character who has super human strength and generally throws large objects or hit's enemies with them to attack. I might be able to convince a dm to make a feat that allows me to pick up large objects to use as improvised weapons. I mean why use a mace when hitting an enemy with an uprooted tree or boulder is so much cooler..

Comment: @MageintheBarrel see also The Rule of Cool by Matt Mercer:
https://geekandsundry.com/game-master-tips-with-matt-mercer-rule-of-cool/